# Playing Audio using AVPlayer in Collection View

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionview, avplayer

I am using `AVPlayer` to play Audio in Collection View Cells (Radio App). Application works, however, If play button on All cells is tapped, All stations play together, until manually stopped (please see the screenshot two players are playing at the same time).

What I would like to do is that if play button on one cell is pressed, other playing players should stop. Any help will be appreciated.

```
player = AVPlayer(url: "some url")
  func togglePlayer() {
        if player?.rate != 0 {
            player?.pause()
            self.playButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(systemName: "play.circle"), for: .normal)
        } else {
            player?.play()
            self.playButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(systemName: "stop"), for: .normal)
        }
    }
```

[image: all players playing simultaneously]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is to add

```swift
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems?.filter({ $0.section == indexPath.section }).forEach({ collectionView.deselectItem(at: $0, animated: false) })
        
        return true
    }
```

This will make it so only one cell inside a given section can be selected at once
or

```swift
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems?.forEach({ collectionView.deselectItem(at: $0, animated: false) })
        
        return true
    }
```

This will make it so only one cell in any given section can be selected at once.

so pick which ever you prefer and override `isSelected` in your custom cell and make it play when isSelected is true and pause when isSelected is false.

```swift
public override var isSelected: Bool {
        didSet {
            switch self.isSelected {
            case true:
                //play audio
            case false:
                //pause audio
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try

1- Make the player object inside the vc

2- Add play action of button that's inside the cell to the vc preferably with `addTarget` action

3- Add current `playIndex` inside the vc initially make it a nil `Int`

4- Set the button tag to `indexPath.row` iside `celloForRowAt` and play button status to whether `indexpath.row` equal to `playIndex` or not

5- Inside the button action set `playIndex` to `sender.tag`

6- Refresh the collection and start playing the selected url